# Android app compiling is ridiculously long with Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to migrate my app from the old Admob SDK to that new Google Play services thing to serve ads. I did everything as it was said and it works.

But now I have a really big problem. Because of this, deployment became ridiculously long and CPU exhausting process. What is happening is that when I want to upload an app through ADB, compiling takes like 2 minutes longer (before it was almost instantaneous) and most of the time Eclipse (latest) becomes unstable and I just have to kill it, otherwise it never ends and gets stuck with 500+mb memory, making whole computer lag.

I'm not using the GPlay Services for anything else but Ads.

This is a huge WTF and it appears I have no other choice, since Google will not accept new apps with legacy Admob SDK.

Anyone know why is this is happening?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post rants on your own blog.

Comment: You obviously failed to see the question in this. It wasn't a rant and I want to know why this is happening. There I added it so you can understand.

Comment: "You obviously failed to see the question in this" -- that is because there was no question. "It wasn't a rant" -- your current second-to-last paragraph alone makes it a rant. With regards to your actual problem, see how much free system RAM your development machine has. If it has a fair bit, and if you have not done so already, try increasing the amount of memory you allocate to Eclipse. There are recipes for that floating around, adding (or revising) the `-Xmx` switch in an Eclipse configuration file. If you are memory bound, close other programs or increase the amount of RAM in your system.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me if I leave "build automatically" turned on while exporting a signed build from Eclipse.  It's not specifically related to Google Play; it does this with any build of significant size.  It's apparently a race condition within Eclipse itself.

This has been a problem at least since 3.7, and persists in 4.x, along with numerous other issues that render 4.x totally unusable.  I am constantly amazed that the most popular program used by programmers to write other programs is such a complete piece of shit.